# Autocorrect had my name wrong and it’s less than 48 hours

Tags: transit, tickets

My wife booked ticket but autocorrect misspell her name and her brother. We were able to correct one one airlines (wizzair) but Ryanair asking for 180£ for just add and deleting one word in each name.

What are my options. Can I board the plain. The itinerary is JED-BUD-STN, we change airlines at BUD (Budapest)

Comment: Anecdotally, I have managed to travel on ryanair before with an error in my name on the ticket, but it was a small enough error that it was clearly the same person and just a typo. If the change required is big enough that it could be construed as changing the ticket to a different person, you probably need to pay up.

Comment: Ryanair isn’t noted for having a understanding attitude towards such things. My guess is you’ll have to pay up if you want to fly

Comment: What is less than 48 hours and what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @FreeMan just as a reference if it is less than 48 hours no airline would let u change free of charge. If it is outside (before 48) hours then they do free of charge

Comment: Auto-correcting someone's name is beyond belief. If someone can spell *anything*, it is their name.

Comment: @WeatherVane if u r familiar with Muslim/Arabic names they do autocorrect or e.g. when u r typing it will auto select the correct one. A example is when u write f**k, it becomes duck and ppl who r less knowledgeable wouldn’t know.